# How can I use Geth to get all tokens on an Ethereum address?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20

Having an ETH address, how can I programmatically see what tokens are on this address?

Currently I have a list of tokens and a loop that checks balance on the ETH address for each contract address, but this naive approach seems to be slow and rather complex - `O(n)`, where `n` is number of all available ERC20 tokens.

How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: so you have one contract which contains mapping for tokens to addresses ? If that is the case there is no other choice other than running a loop

Comment: I'm about to tackle a similar problem. I guess the first option would be to run the requests in parallel, if possible. Also, if the bottleneck is in the sending/receiving of data rather than the actual processing time for a balance request on a node, you could develop a smart contract which retrieves balances for multiple tokens in a single request.